# Classic exercises for computer vision / image processing?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, opencv

For a mentoring project, I am looking for an online repository of classic computer vision exercises, similar to [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems), but geared towards image processing problems that could be solved in MATLAB or OpenCV.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Many computer vision university courses are online including their work assignments.
[CVonline](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/) would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a place for standard problems and test data for them in CV.

Here is one for [Object Recognition](http://vision.stanford.edu/teaching.html).

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember [hackthissite](http://www.hackthissite.org) having a few image-related [steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography) challenges (the site is down atm).

Not exactly the classics (you might have to take a CV class for that), but definitely fun.